# how can I move account owner alias field from the data loader

Tags: apex, community, data-loader, metadata

I have moved all the account data in another org through data loader but in the account owner alias field it is showing admin, I have to show the user perspective shot name. Thanks in advance

Comment: Does it also show the admin as the account owner?

Comment: Are you importing the account owner field in data loader? Do all of the users exist in both the source and target orgs? If the users do exist you would need to map the id from the source to the target on the owning users probably by matching names in text format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Account owner's alias is part of the User record that's linked through the Account's `OwnerId` relationship. If you did not load the `OwnerId` field when you did your data load (which sounds like it is the case), the running user for the data load was automatically assigned ownership of all of the records.

To fix this, you'd need to obtain the original ownership data from your source org and perform a Data Loader update. To do so, you'll need to use the success file provided by Data Loader to map the Ids in the data from the source org to the new Ids in the destination org using a `VLOOKUP()` or `INDEX/MATCH()` construction in your spreadsheet. This would allow you to create an update file with the new Id and the old OwnerId for each Account and thence perform an update.